# How to show colored bold texts in VS Code integrated terminal?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I want to print some colored bold texts in terminal, but I got bright colored regular texts instead. It seems to me that only white can be displayed in bold size.

For example, when I run `echo -e "\e[1ma"`, I can get a bold letter `a` in white, while running `echo -e "\e[1;31ma"` gives me a regular letter `a` in bright red

update: I found out that when I connect to a server using remote-ssh, I can get colored bold text in terminal as expected. But if I open a terminal in local project, I can only see bright regular text even if I ssh to the server in this terminal.

Comment: the `bold` is an attribute of the color not of the font, `bright` would be a better wording

Answer (score 2):

Search for "bold" in the Settings and disable "Terminal > Integrated: Draw Bold Text In Bright Colors":

[image]

Comment: I have tried this option before, but it made no difference even after i restart VS Code

Answer (score 0):

Look for the "Terminal > Integrated: Minimum Contrast Ratio" setting. It is set to 4.5 by default but setting it to 1 should do the trick.

[image: Minimum Contrast Ratio setting set to 1]